# Why is the center of a rectangle (x+width/2, y+height/2) in Java?

Tags: java, rectangles

Since (x, y) is the upper-left corner of the rectangle, shouldn't the center be (x+width/2, y-height/2)? But the textbook I'm learning says it's the titular point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The upper-left point is (0,0) and positive direction of y-axis is downward, the positive direction of x-axis is rightward.

To make you have a better understanding , refer to the image:

[image]

Assume the rectangle's width is 20 and the height is 15.

If you want to know why it's like this, pls refer to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/83571/48636

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's eye-opening!

Answer (score 0):

In the java, you can say that the Y axis is inverted. Top left corner of the screen is the (0,0) point. If you go to right side of the screen, X increases, if you go down, Y increases. That is why y+height/2 is used instead of y-height/2. An example is shown in the image below.

[image]